# ArrayOutOfBoundsException when decoding message

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting an 'array out of bounds' exception, when I run the following code. Basically I am sending two TLV encoded strings from a client to a server, and the server decodes the TLV encoded values and prints them to the screen.

code to print decoded values

```
byte[] from_ca = new byte[65536];
int msg = is.read(from_ca, 0, 65536);
from_ca = Arrays.copyOfRange(from_ca, 0, msg);
Object[] decodeBytes = TLV.decode(from_ca);

String ca_id = (String) decodeBytes[0];
String cb_id = (String) decodeBytes[1];
```

code in TLV class for decoding

```
public static Object[] decode(byte[] data) throws Exception {
    int i = 0;
    List<Object> tlvList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    while (i < data.length) {
        if (data[i] == TLV.ascii) {
            int length = (256 * data[i + 2]) + data[i + 1];
            tlvList.add(new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, i + 3, i + 3 + length), "US-ASCII"));
            i = i + 3 + length;

        } else if (data[i] == TLV.integer) {
            int length = (256 * data[i + 2]) + data[i + 1];
            tlvList.add(Integer.parseInt(new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(
            data, i + 3, i + 3 + length), "US-ASCII")));
            i = i + 3 + length;

        } else if (data[i] == TLV.binary) {
            int length = (256 * data[i + 2]) + data[i + 1];
            tlvList.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, i + 3, i + 3 + length));
            i = i + 3 + length;

        }
    } // end of loop
    return tlvList.toArray(new Object[tlvList.size()]);
}
```

I get the following exception when I run the program:

```
an error has occurred
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at ServerConnection.run(Server.java: 131)
At java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I would appreciate any help debugging the problem further or even a solution if possible.

Comment: Which line is line 131 of Server.java?

Comment: Please edit your code to indent it more readably. It's horribly hard to read at the moment. (Why are you copying byte arrays when constructing strings, by the way? Just use the overloaded String constructor which allows you to specify the starting index.)

Comment: It seems, when you are trying to copy array range, the `i + 3` or `i + 3 + length` is going out of range. Add a validation for this to consider minimum of computed index or length of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probaby this line causing you Exception

```
  int length = (256 * data[i + 2]) + data[i + 1];
```

when counter `(i)` reaches `data.length` then  `data [i+2]` and `data[i + 1]` will exceed array ranges.

Comment: I should add that the program prints 'String ca_id = (String) decodeBytes[0];' with no problem, it's when I try accessing decodeBytes[1];' i get the exception.

Comment: @user1896168 I tried to reproduce your problem and I see everything all right. Possibility could be your passing `data` or returning values from method could cause this issue. See if `decodeBytes.length` is 2 adn contains your returned data.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it's the only one to give anything constructive... I still haven't found the problem but I expect it's something wrong with the array I'm returning from the function.

Comment: @user1896168 If this answer dont solve your problem then dont accept it, if someone see it then that person could give the answer. In my opinion. Just try to return the arraylist as `return tlvList.toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating up to `i < data.length` but then you're trying to access `data[i + 1]` and `data[i + 2]`.

You should do

`while (i < data.length - 2)` instead.